# Evaluate the integral $I=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin^{2}u}{u^{2}}du$

Tags: fourier-analysis, definite-integrals

To evaluate this integral I have got to use Parseval's Theorem and the fourier transform of

$$s(x)=\begin{cases}
0  & x\leq -a \\
1 & -a<x<a \\
0 & x \geq a.\end{cases}$$

This works out to be

$$\tilde{s}(k)=\frac{e^{ika}}{ik}-\frac{e^{-ika}}{ik}$$

I have then changed this into sin and cos and got to the stage of

$$|\tilde{s}(k)|^{2}=\left|\frac{-4\sin^{2}(ka)}{-k^{2}}\right|$$

but this is as far as I have got and I can't figure out what to do from here.

Comment: Why not rewrite the given integral as one involving an integrand of $|\tilde{s}|^2$, and then using Parseval's equate it to an integral of $|s|^2$, which is easy to evaluate.

Answer (score 5):

The FT of $f(x) = \sin{x}/x$ is

$$\hat{f}(k) = \begin{cases} \\\pi & |k| < 1 \\ 0 & |k| > 1 \end{cases}$$

Parseval's theorem then implies that

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} dx \frac{\sin^2{x}}{x^2} = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-1}^1 dk \: \pi^2 = \pi $$

Answer (score 0):

Take $a=1$ in your function $s(x)$. The Fourier transform of $s$ is $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-1}^1 e^{-iwx}\,dx=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\frac{\sin w}{w} $$ Then Parseval (also called Plancherel) relation says $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{2}{\pi}\frac{\sin^2w}{w^2}\,dw = \int_{-1}^1 1^2\,dx=2.$$